# Horizontal sticky element flickers (shifts for a split seconds) when height is changes

Tags: sticky, flicker

I have a sticky element on left side that container (100vh - some header height ) and right side non-sticky elements (normal scroll flow). While the element when becomes stuck has no issue. I have a design where when footers comes in viewport the sticky element's height need to be reduced (similar to git-hub file changes view).
Only when footer comes into view and height is reduced. I noticed that sticky element shifts up and then down within a fraction of seconds. Is there any reason for that?

I tried having both top & bottom value as well. Nothing changed and I don't have any clue on fixing it

Just need to know why such flicker is there on my browser (chrome, firefox and safari)

Comment: It works okay on my browser, could you share [some code that shows the flickering in action](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.